# Sitecore item data fetch on the basis of language if wrong language append goes to 404 page

Tags: sxa, multilingual

I am getting stuck with an issue, I have a `Multilanguage` site that is based on `SXA`. Rather than going to change via language drop-down, I am going to change language via URL.

Please see the steps below what I made for reproducing this issue:

1. first of all I have two language site which is `en-ca` and `fr-Ca`. `en-ca` is the default one.
2. I have a `product` page that exists in both languages.
3. When I try to hit the URL like: `https://domainname/en-ca/product` for `en-ca` result will be correct. Now rather than changing the item language from the language selector dropdown, I tried to change the URL from the above to like: `https://domainname/fr-ca/product`. After hitting the same page will load and get data from `fr-ca` language.
4. But it goes to the `404` page, because no product name like this exists in the content tree for `fr-ca` since I have changed the name of the product item in `fr-ca` to products.

So my concern is that rather than resolving an item via its item name, I want to resolve it via display name.

Anyone, please suggest to me the better way how I can handle this?

Comment: For this you need to create custom ItemResolver, you can follow this - https://keeplearningandsharing.wordpress.com/tag/custom-item-resolver/

Comment: You can use simillar kind of approach and tweek it. For creating friendly names for products, you can follow this [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/82/sitecore-commerce/create-friendly-urls-for-catalog-items.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have enabled language embedding field in Site Grouping item (/sitecore/content/TENANT/YOURSITEfolder/YOURSITE/Settings/Site Grouping) like below:

[image]

Also, please provide your Sitecore and SXA version so that it might be easy for community members to suggest solutions.